# Order email not receiving

Tags: magento2

when the order is placed not receiving the order confirmation mail.
Even from the back end when I send email to customer it is not working.
I have updated the back-end but still, it is not working in magneto 2.1.7

**[EDIT]**

When I send the mail from the admin sales->order->view->send mail is working

Comment: check if the email function is working for other functions, like forget password. Try to reset the password admin/ customer.

Comment: Yes it is working for forget password\

Comment: I have also checked the cron is working by script and it is working

Comment: have you referred https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152799/order-confirmation-email-not-send-in-magento-2 ?

Comment: Yes i have implemented the changes on admin

Comment: does it work? if not, have you customized the order module? and also check if emails are getting spammed

Comment: when i send the mail from the admin sales->order->view->send mail is working

Comment: but not from the site

Comment: Check the error log files